# Watch recursive scss files in gulp

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm using gulp for compiling several themes from a base theme. If I make changes to a subfile "watch" does not recognize the changes. It only recognize the changes if a file of those themes is changed.

My folder structure

```
├── node_modules
├── src/
│   ├── base/
│   │   ├── bootstrap
│   │   └── custom
│   ├── themes/
│   │   ├── theme1.scss
│   │   └── theme2.scss
│   └── main.scss
└── gulpfile.js
```

theme1.scss imports main.scss
main.scss imports all bootstrap files and the _all.scss from custom dir.

My gulp config:

```
gulp.task('styles', function () {
    gulp.src('src/themes/*.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('/'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/themes'));
});
```

if I try to use `src/**/*.scss` as `gulp.src` it tries to compile every single file inside `src/base/bootstrap` and `src/base/custom` and crashes, because the variables can't be found.

What I want to achieve:
Watcher sees changes in `src/base/custom/_header.scss` and compiles `theme1.scss` and `theme2.scss`

Can anyone help me setting my configuration accordingly?

Comment: It is necessary to tell us which version of gulp you are using.  What does `gulp -v` in your terminal show?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a watcher-task. You need to have a different set of files to watch and a different set to compile.

Define a watcher-task with a `glob`of files to watch:

**Gulp 4**

```
// Watch for file changes in any .scss file
gulp.task("watch-styles", function () {
    return gulp.watch(['src/**/*.scss'], gulp.series('styles'));
    //return gulp.watch(['src/base/custom/_header.scss'], gulp.series('styles'));
});
```

**Gulp 3**

```
// Watch for file changes in any .scss file
gulp.task("watch-styles", function() {
  var watcher = gulp.watch(['src/**/*.scss'], ['styles']);
  //var watcher = gulp.watch(['src/base/custom/_header.scss'], ['styles']);
});
```

Your compiling function stays the same. Here the `src` `glob` points to the files you want to compile:

```
gulp.task('styles', function () {
    gulp.src('src/themes/*.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('/'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/themes'));
});
```

Comment: This answer is in gulp3 syntax.  If the OP is using gulp4, the watch tasks will not work as presented.

Comment: As you can observe, the question is in gulp3 syntax. Therefore the answer is in gulp3 syntax.

Comment: No, you cannot tell from any of the OP's code whether he is using gulp3 or gulp4.  His code while in gulp3 style works perfectly well in gulp4.  Your answer code would not work in gulp4.  He may very well be using gulp4.

Comment: You're right, i'll edit the response. I automatically assumed it was 3 since the format is not the one suggested for 4.